# Error when try to import axios on iOS platform

Tags: react-native, axios

I create a React-Native project using Windows 10 and it works perfectly on Android.

I copy the files to my iMac and run the project in the iOS platform, but when I try to run the project in iOS I got the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `axios` from `/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/src/components/Login.js`: Module does not exist in the module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:158:1476)
at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:92:16)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:271:4465)
at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:379:19)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at resolveDependencies (/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:378:16)
at /Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:203:33
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:296:307)
at /Users/fabio/react/VirtusVSTS/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:296:467
```

The problem is related to the axis import.

I try to create a new project in my iMac and import axis on it. It works perfectly.

But now I don't know what is happening with the project that I create on Windows, why it can't import the axis module on iMac.

I run all the steps that appear in the error message to try to fix the problem, but it won't work.

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Axios works on iOS too. I don't know if this will help but every time I have the errors you mention above I 
1. close all instances of the react-packager terminal, 
2. delete the node_modules folder
3. run npm install and then react-native run-ios.

Comment: I already did that, following the steps of the error that was showed in React-Native screen. Still it not works.

Comment: Are you sure axios is in your package.json and exists in your node_modules folder? How do you import it?

Comment: @needsleep I check my node_modules folder now, for my surprise the axios folder is not present inside the project. I add the files to git, but I didn't include the node_modules folder when I use my windows pc, then i clone the git repository in my Mac and use npm install, for some reason the axios folder is not created. Now I add the entire node_modules folder to the git repository and clone in Mac, it works now. Thank you. ps: I need to manually install some jest modules

Comment: Never add the node_modules to git. The purpose of package.json is for any dev to install all necessary dependencies just by running npm install.  The axios folder was missing probably because it was installed as "npm install axios" and not "npm install axios --save"" and that is why it was missing from your package.json. You should add the missing jest modules you mentioned the same way "npm install somePackageName --save-dev"

Comment: @needsleep, thanks for the tip, I will remove the node_modules from git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axios module folder is not present in my node_modules folder. The comments from user @needsleep help me understand why the axios module was not present in my React Native project.
I begin to use Yarn and use it to install the axios module(yarn add axios) and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

remove axios and after in install using yarn and it's working fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).